# Cant Head section contain any tags?

Tags: html

From Richard Kiessig's ultra fast asp.net book,

Head section can't contain any tags that cause the browser to draw content on the screen, users will see noting until it has downloaded all resources in the  section.

-- What he is referring from this statement?

```
<HEAD runat ="server">
        <title>WebForm1</title>
        <h1> Hi </h1>
    </HEAD>
```

Browser is rending 'hi'.

Comment: `<h>` isn't even a valid tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, sure the `<head></head>` can contain all tags that by default carry the `display:none;` property. Those are elements like `<meta>` and `<title>`. But `<h1>` has to render on the screen, it is `display:inline;`. Most elements aren't `display:none;` though, and should be placed in the `<body></body>` section.

At that point it won't validate with w3c therefore you're breaking web standards. However, it should render just fine in all modern browsers. Most people would say you want to retain organization and quality when building web pages, part of that is making sure your code is the correct syntax.

ETA: Standard HTML5 markup...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>

        <section>
        </section>

        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

In that lt IE9 comment, it adds HTML5 support to IE 8 and below which do not support it. ;-)

Comment: At that point it won't validate with w3c therefore you're breaking web standards  - Didnt get you Jackson

Comment: W3c (world wide web consortium) manages web standards and is a basis to help web developers use one technology for the web. The web is easier to use when we all decide on a few technologies to use (CSS, HTML, JS, PHP etc.) rather then every site using its own language.

Comment: W3C states that we should be using HTML4 and CSS2. That's the standard. You can check if your code has the correct HTML4/CSS2 syntax at this site: http://validator.w3.org

Comment: No u mean, display:inline tags should not be inside html tags as per the w3c standard?

Comment: Recently, HTML5 and CSS3 were added to the validator, but it still displays a message saying "this was checked using the HTML5 validator" since many internet users' browsers still don't allow HTML5/CSS3 code. W3C will help web developers ease into new languages/technologies to create a more transparent development environment.

Comment: @Ala display:inline tags should not be within the <head></head> section of your markup. They can be in <body>.

Comment: display:inline tags should not be within the <head></head> section of your markup. -> Is it as per W3c Standard?

Comment: Yeah. W3C says it should be valid HTML4/HTML5. HTML4 and HTML5 both say no tags that use display:inline; should be in the <head></head> section, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks alot +1 and fine answer

Answer (score 3):

`h1` inside `head` is invalid html. It is not allowed. But if producers of webbrowsers would reject every invalid html-document, about 90% (or even more) websites would not displayed to the user.

So one browser producer built a browser who was able to render invalid sites too, and all the user started to use this browser. So the producers of correct webbrowsers had no other chance. They also built browsers that can render invalid html. And because of this, all webbrowsers that are in use are browsers that are able to render invalid html.

BUT:

There is no standard defined on how to render invalid html. So each producer has his own ideas about how to display an invalid document, and so, when you write invalid html, you could have luck, and the document looks fine in the one browser you used for developing and testing. But the users of your website do not only use YOUR browser. They use ALL available browsers, and if your html-code is invalid, the chances are really high, that many users use a browser you dont know, and this browser don't display what you want, but some garbage.

Conclusio:

- Producers of really good Web-Browsers MUST produce browsers that can render any garbage.
- Producers of really good html-documents MUST procuce valid html.

Answer (score 2):

The statement “Head section can't contain any tags that cause the browser to draw content on the screen, users will see noting until it has downloaded all resources in the section.” is best ignored; it just causes confusion and lacks a point. Trying to correct the mistakes in it would take long and would not really lead to anything.

Regarding the treatment of the invalid markup

```
<HEAD runat ="server">
        <title>WebForm1</title>
        <h1> Hi </h1>
    </HEAD>
```

the simple answer is that browsers have parsers that imply a closing `</head>` tag and an opening `<body>` tag, when they encounter `<h1>` while parsing a `head` element. This is in full conformance with HTML specifications.

In the fragment, the only invalid thing, apart from the `runat ="server"` attribute, which is not expected to be delivered to clients at all (it’s ASP not HTML), is the spurious end tag `</HEAD>`. The `head` element was already closed, it cannot be closed again.